# gradle-cargo-plugin: How to add jars to the server's lib directory?

Tags: deployment, gradle, jboss5.x, cargo

I am using the cargoStartLocal task to deploy an ear module to a JBoss 5.1.x container. My cargo config looks like this:

```
cargo {
    containerId = 'jboss51x'

    local {
        homeDir = file(jbossHome)
        configHomeDir = file(jbossHome+"/server/test")
    }
}
```

This creates a jbossHome/server/test folder tree with an empty jbossHome/server/test/lib directory.

I would like to know how I can add a jar to this folder during the cargoStartLocal task.

I will add the correct answer with attribution to the wiki at https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin/wiki if I have access. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using multiple configFile closures...

```
    cargo {
        containerId = 'jboss51x'

        local {
            homeDir = file(JBOSS_DIST)
            configHomeDir = file(JBOSS_DIST+'/server/' + JBOSS_SERVER_CONFIG)

            configFile {
                file = file('../../x/y/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar')
                toDir = 'lib'
            }
            // ....
        }
}
```